# pidof from a background script for another background process

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote a c++ program to check if a process is running or not . this process is independently launched at background . my program works fine when I run it on foreground but when I time schedule it, it do not work .

```
int PID=  ReadCommanOutput("pidof /root/test/testProg1"); /// also tested with pidof -m
```

I made a script in /etc/cron.d/myscript to time schedule it as follows :-

```
45 15 * * * root /root/ProgramMonitor/./testBkg > /root/ProgramMonitor/OutPut.txt
```

what could be the reason for this ?

```
     string ReadCommanOutput(string command)
      {
          string output="";
          int its=system((command+" > /root/ProgramMonitor/macinfo.txt").c_str());
          if(its==0)
           {
                  ifstream reader1("/root/ProgramMonitor/macinfo.txt",fstream::in);
                  if(!reader1.fail())
                     {
                      while(!reader1.eof())
                       {

                          string line;
                          getline(reader1,line);
                          if(reader1.fail())// for last read
                          break;
                          if(!line.empty())
                          {
                             stringstream ss(line.c_str());
                             ss>>output;
                             cout<<command<<" output = ["<<output<<"]"<<endl;
                              break;
                         }
                }
                reader1.close();
                remove("/root/ProgramMonitor/macinfo.txt");
               }
             else
                cout<<"/root/ProgramMonitor/macinfo.txt not found !"<<endl;
         }
         else
           cout<<"ERROR: code = "<<its<<endl;
      return output;
     }
```

its output coming as "ERROR: code = 256"

thanks in advacee .

Comment: You should edit your question to show more code, in particular the code of your `ReadCommanOutput`

Comment: Please dump your `ReadCommanOutput` to garbage, and use `popen`

Comment: I already used popen sir , it didn't worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by using su command

I have used

```
         ReadCommanOutput("su -c 'pidof /root/test/testProg1' - root");
```

insteadof

```
         ReadCommanOutput("pidof /root/test/testProg1");
```

Comment: whats that ? please redirect me towards it .

Comment: If you can run `su` for root without password, you have a big security hole.

Answer (score 2):

If you really wanted to [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) then read the output of a `pidof` command, you should at least use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) since `ReadCommandOutput` is not in the Posix API; at the very least

```
 pid_t thepid = 0;
 FILE* fpidof = popen("pidof /root/test/testProg1");
 if (fpidof) {
    int p=0;
    if (fscanf(fpidof, "%d", &p)>0 && p>0) 
       thepid = (pid_t)p;
    pclose(fpidof);
 }
```

<sup>BTW, you did not specify what should happen if several processes (or none) are running the `testProg1`....; you also need to check the result of `pclose`</sup>

But you don't need to; actually you'll want to build, perhaps using `snprintf`, the `pidof` command (and you should be scared of [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) into that command, so quote arguments appropriately). You could simply find your command by accessing the [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file system: you would [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) on `"/proc/"`, then loop on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) and for every entry which has a numerical name like 1234 (starts with a digit) [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) its `exe` entry like e.g. `/proc/1234/exe` ...). Don't forget the `closedir` and test every syscall.

Please read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Notice that libraries like [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) or toolkits like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (which has a layer `QCore` without any GUI, and providing `QProcess` ....) could be useful to you.

As to why your `pidof` is failing, we can't guess (perhaps a permission issue, or perhaps there is no more any process like you want). Try to run it as root in another terminal at least. Test its exit code, and display both its *stdout* & *stderr* at least for debugging purposes.

Also, a better way (assuming that `testProg1` is some kind of a server application, to be run in at most one single process) might be to define different conventions. Your `testProg1` might start by writing its own pid into `/var/run/testProg1.pid` and your current application might then read the pid from that file and check, with [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) and a 0 signal number, that the process is still existing.

BTW, you could also improve your [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry. You could make it run some shell script which uses [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) and (for debugging) runs `pidof` with its output redirected elsewhere. You might also read the mail perhaps sent to `root` by `cron`.

Comment: sorry Sir I did not mentioned that ReadCommandOutput is my own function which returns output of a command by first writing it into a text file and then return it by reading that text file  .

Comment: Yes, but that is a big mistake. Use `popen` at the very least! And I'm guessing your `ReadCommandOutput` is buggy (probably does not check for failure of syscalls).

Comment: I replaced my code in ReadCommandOutput with  your code gien above. it runs fine from foreground but when I time scheduled it , it is printing pid=0 . I am working the other sight you have mentioned above i.e testProg1 will write its pid . thanks a lot for your responses .

Comment: I have edited my question by appending my function's code . thanks